# Why is max stack depth keeping changing?

Tags: c, windows

For following code, the last output (which is max stack depth is keeping changing):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int depth=0;

void func(){
    int x=depth;
    printf("%d\n",depth++);
    func();  
    printf("%d\n",x);
}

int main(){
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

// compiled by `cl /F 1 test.c`

The first time is `3717`, the second is `3700`, the third is `3695`.

I thought for constant stack size, max stack depth should be constant. but why is it changing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: I can replicate that with MSVC (although it goes to 60000 ish) and adding `fflush(stdout)` makes no difference. When I print the stack pointer at the start of the program I get different values. Perhaps it has something to do with address space randomization, but I was unaware that it varies the stack **size** too. That might be done by the code that calls `main` to make its own stack use inconsistent, and make an attack more difficult.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Microsoft Windows platform running x86/x64 CPUs, the memory reserved for the stack always ends on a [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)) boundary and a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) will occur when the stack grows beyond that page boundary. A page is normally 4096 bytes of memory.

Without [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (ASLR), the stack will also start at a page boundary, which means the maximum stack size will be a multiple of the page size. By default, the stack has a maximum size of 1 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte), which is 256 pages of 4096 bytes.

However, with ASLR active, the starting address of the stack is no longer on a page boundary, but is random. Since the memory reserved for the stack still ends on a page boundary, this means that the maximum stack size is random and is no longer a multiple of the page size.

This randomness of the maximum stack size is the reason why the time of the stack overflow is also random.

The Microsoft linker builds executable files with ASLR enabled by default. In order to disable ASLR, you must add the `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` option when invoking the linker. Afterwards, the stack overflow should occur at exactly the same time whenever you run your program.

Comment: Exactly! BTW, the option `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` is not enough, the full option should be like `cl test.c /F 1 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /link /FIXED`.

Comment: @RobertLu: Calling `cl test.c /F 1 /link /DYNAMICBASE:NO` works with me. The `/link` option must appear before the `/DYNAMICBASE:NO` option, because it is a linker option, not a compiler option. The `/FIXED` option is unnecessary.